# Angular 6 infinite scroll (scrolled) not working

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll

Good afternoon dear friends, I have some problems with my scroll event when I use **infinite-scroll** library. I have read that when I use **(scrolled)** - this will callback if the distance has been reached on a scroll down.
But, unfortunatelly it *works after every scroll*, not after we reach down of the page. I don`t understand what is wrong with my code:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onOtherTabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Posts" matTabContent infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="1000" (scrolled)="onScroll()">
    <ng-template>
      <app-add-post [profile]="profile"></app-add-post>
        <app-post [posts]="posts"></app-post>  
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Also I want to listen the scroll of my browser window, that is why I don`t use **[scrollWindow]="false"**

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the scroll distance? You can adjust to your window size:

- **infiniteScrollDistance** - (optional, default: 2) -

The bottom percentage point of the scroll nob relatively to the infinite-scroll container (i.e, `2 (2 * 10 = 20%)` is event is triggered when 80% (100% - 20%) has been scrolled)

If container.height is `900px`, when the container is scrolled to or past the `720px`, it will fire the scrolled event.